# How to add custom sidebar to a mainWindow in electorn when loading an external url(eg: mainWindow.loadURL("https://gmail.com") )

Tags: electron

I am trying to build a desktop app that opens gmail in a webview using electron. In my main file I have loaded the url like this `mainWindow.loadURL("https://gmail.com")`
I was looking for a way to add a custom side bar in my app , but for that I will have to load my own html file in the main window. Is it possible to load gmail.com as the url but still be able to add a custom sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to load your own HTML file which contains your app (this is a good idea anyway). There, you can render the side bar.

And you can load gmail (or any other web site) in a `<webview>` tag, which is a little bit like an `iframe`, only safer:

https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag

Comment: I didn't want to use an iframe. Thanks for suggesting webview, did not know about them.